# Find roots of a trigonometric equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I've been struggling on find the roots of this equation for a while.

$$
f(x)=\cos(2x) - 2\sin(x)\cos(x).
$$

I've already ended transforming all $\cos$ relation to $\sin$ ones, but I'm now stuck on:

$$
f(x)=1-2\sin^2(x) - \sin(2x).
$$

What should I do now?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have

> $$f(x)=\cos(2x)-2\sin(x)\cos(x).$$

The roots will satisfy $f(x)=0$, i.e. $$\cos(2x)-2\sin(x)\cos(x)=0$$ and so $\cos(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$.

Now, $2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\sin(2x)$, so you have $$\cos(2x)=\sin(2x),$$ and from here, hopefully you can see what to do.

Comment: Nice answer, welcome on MSE!

Answer (score 4):

Since
$$
f(x)=\cos(2x)-2\sin(x)\cos(x)=\cos(2x)-\sin(2x)=\cos(2x)-\cos(2x-\frac\pi2),
$$
we have
$$
f(x)=0\iff \cos(2x)=\cos(2x-\frac\pi2) \iff 2x=-2x+\frac\pi2+2k\pi, \ k \in \mathbb{Z},
$$
i.e.
$$
x=\frac\pi8+k\frac\pi2,\quad k \in \mathbb{Z}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f(x)=\cos{(2x)}-\sin{(2x)}=\sqrt{2}\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\cos{(2x)}-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\sin{(2x)}\right)=\sqrt{2}\left(\sin{\frac{\pi}{4}}\cos{(2x)}-\cos{\frac{\pi}{4}}\sin{(2x)}\right)=\sqrt{2}\sin{\left(\frac{\pi}{4}-2x\right)}$

Answer (score 1):

A faster solution: We get $\cos(2x) - \sin(2x)= 0$, or $\tan(2x) = 1$. The solution to this is $2x = \dfrac{\pi}{4} + k\pi, \ \ k \in \mathbb{Z}$, or $$x = \dfrac{\pi}{8} + k\dfrac{\pi}{2}, \ \ k \in \mathbb{Z}$$